# Can't get dotCMS installed

Tags: java, tomcat, content-management-system, dotcms

I have downloaded dotCMS zip folder and war file. I have been looking at the install instructions for windows which says to use the exe file and install from there. There is no exe file in the folders and the windows batch startup file does not run when exe in cmd... I tried to start the tomcat server then as well which was also a no go. Every tutorial I look up online tells me to do something different and the one on the dotCMS site...like I said, I HAVE NO EXE FILE!! This is the first time I have used a content management system so I just need some pointing in the right direction :p Any help at all would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: the zip file does not contain an exe file. It only contains the dotCMS folder including tomcat and all source files. You can download the exe file from the dotCMS download page: http://dotcms.com/downloads/index.dot.

Alternatively you can download the zip file. extract it into a folder somewhere, install java (use the jdk if you want to develop plugins), and mysql (or postgresql, mssql, etc) and hook the stuff up yourself. How this is done can be read here: http://dotcms.com/docs/1.9/WindowsInstall